# Import SQLClient into existing Xcode (Swift) project

Tags: swift, xcode

I've never messed with iOS so this is all new to me. I'm trying to import SQLClient into an an existing Xcode project. (I need to fire off an INSERT from the iOS app.)

https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient

I've tried both installation methods listed by Martin via `cocoapods` and manual but I can't get either to work.

For option #1) everything worked fine until I tried `pod install` and was met with

Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `SQLClient (~> 0.1.3)` is not used in any concrete target.

I was expecting the command to produce a file named `SQLClient.xcworkspace`. I wasn't sure if this new xcworkspace file was meant to replace my main project xcode file. But since it didn't work, I moved onto option #2.

For option #2 I wasn't sure where to put the contents. (Does Martin mean `/SQLClient/SQLClient/SQLClient/SQLClient` or `/SQLClient/SQLClient/SQLClient`?)

Was I supposed to copy just the files or the whole folder? 
Do the contents go into my project at the same level as my original xcode project file or in a subfolder? 
I've tried a couple variations but I admittedly don't know where the SQLClient files/folders should be placed in relation to my other project files.

I've tried messing with my bridge file as well but I've been unable to properly load it.

I have some time (2 days) to figure this out so I'm willing to learn but I need some guidance.

Here's a pic of my existing Xcode project and latest attempt to import SQLClient.[image]

Comment: can you show us your Podfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get installation option #1 working after changing the pod file to include a target.

```
target "TargetName" do
pod 'SQLClient', '~> 0.1.3'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have all the files in your project correctly.

Things to check.

If you said yes to create the bridge file when you dragged the object-c file into the project then you just need to add `#import "SQLClient.h"` to the bridge file. If you created the bridge file manually make sure it is added to Build Settings - Objective-C Bridging Header.

Make sure in your target - general - linked framework and libraries you have `libiconv.tb` and `libfreetds.a`

**Swift 3**

```
class testViewController: UIViewController, SQLClientDelegate {
      // Handles errors from the SQLClient
      func error(_ error: String!, code: Int32, severity: Int32) {
            print("\(error!) \(code) \(severity)")
      }
       //MARK: Lifecyle
      override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
           client.delegate = self
           client.connect("ServerNameOrIP", username: "cool", password: "cool", database: "database") { success in
           client.execute("SELECT * FROM table", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
            for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                for row in table {
                    for (columnName, value) in row {
                        print("\(columnName) = \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
            client.disconnect()
        })
    }
   } 
 }
```

Created a sample project [here](https://bitbucket.org/mwcs01/mssqlswift)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I was able to get a fix by adding a target to my pod file. Awesomely, you've given me an example of how to implement SQLClient using swift3 -- which was my next priority. Thanks!

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the solution.  And give mine an up vote for helping in next step.

Comment: I just tried to choose my own answer but it said it needs 22 hours before it will accept. I also upvoted your comment but something about my karma not being high enough or something. Anyways, I really do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded SQLClient manually and it worked for me.You will get the steps to connect from swift project from here - https://github.com/salmasumona/Call-SP-from-iOS-project-using-SQLClient

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgS0z.png)The best way to use Obj-C in a Swift project is to use a bridging header file, what I did with SQLCLient was to drag and drop the files from SQL client and then Xcode will ask if you want to create a bridging header file, select yes.

Inside the bridging header file, import "SQLClient.h", from here you can build the project and everything should compile. You can then create a SQLClient object like you did above and inside the .connect you make the sure the completion handler checks if it was successful then inside the closure you can call client.execute and from here if you put a SQL command as a string and use data as a variable inside the .execute completion block, if you print this data variable you will return all of the data from the SQL Server. It returns in JSON, so from here you can convert using JSON Serialization.

If you have any questions, please feel free to message me and I will return a screenshot of what my code looked like so that it may help you!